# HTTP Request retry on particular error using interceptor and retrywhen

Tags: angular, interceptor, retrywhen

I have a service that makes a call to GET API and receives a response back. I have implemented HTTP Interceptor to properly and globally handle any errors though out the application. I want to do is, when my API returns a particular error, say for example, error 501, I need to retry that request for n no of times and t seconds of delay before every request. I also want to handle a generic error if my retries are over(i.e. if I get error on the last retry, I want to handle it in a particular way). Please help me figure out how to solve this issue.

This is all implemented using Angular 6, solution with correct syntax will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider doing this using `retryWhen`, `delay`, `tap`, `scan` of RxJS. Something like the following code where an Angular service invokes the Google APIs to authenticate a user in an app that doesn't run on a browser, for e.g. a desktop app. This service uses RxJS to retry the REST API calls at a specific interval in case of failure due to unstable internet connection:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { retryWhen, delay, tap, scan, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleDeviceAuthService {

  private readonly client_id = "<client-id>";
  private readonly client_secret = "<client-secret>";

  private readonly userCodeRequest = {
    "client_id": this.client_id,
    "scope": "email profile"
  };

  private readonly pollGoogleAuthServerRequestTemplate = {
    "client_id": this.client_id,
    "client_secret": this.client_secret,
    "code": "",
    "grant_type": "http://oauth.net/grant_type/device/1.0"
  }

  private readonly userCodeUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code";

  private readonly pollGoogleAuthServerUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

  public getUserCode() {
    return this.http.post(this.userCodeUrl, this.userCodeRequest)
      .pipe(
        retryWhen(err => err.pipe(
          scan(
            (retryCount, err) => {
              if (retryCount > 3)
                throw err;
              else
                return retryCount + 1;
            }, 0
          ),
          delay(1000),
          tap(err => console.log("Retrying...", err))
        )));
  }

  public checkAuthServerForUserInput(deviceCode) {
    let pollGoogleAuthServerRequest = { 
        ...this.pollGoogleAuthServerRequestTemplate, 
        ...{ "code": deviceCode } };
    return this.http.post(this.pollGoogleAuthServerUrl, pollGoogleAuthServerRequest)
      .pipe(
        retryWhen(err => err.pipe(
          scan(
            (retryCount, err) => {
              if (retryCount > 3)
                throw err;
              else
                return retryCount + 1;
            }, 0
          ),
          delay(1000),
          tap(err => console.log("Retrying...", err))
        )));;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you think this will override the interceptor I have implemented?

Also, I see you use count variable for retries, can we use retry() method instead?

Comment: @KalyaniShirwalkar - This has nothing to do with interceptor. So, interceptor logic should work as usual. `retryWhen` method is used here. I wanted to have a delay and at the same time retry a fixed number of times. I could not find a better way to acheive this. There maybe a better way which I am not aware of at the moment.

Comment: Actually, is there a way to narrow it down to one error and not all? I tried using error.status but error is of type ProgressEvent which doesn't have status property.

Comment: @KalyaniShirwalkar I'll get back on this shortly. But in case you are in hurry, you might want to `console.log` the error object and see which field contains the  status. If the status is not what you want just throw the error immediately.